# How to add custome label or component in ListGrid Summary?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I want to add custom label positioned freely in ListGrid Summary.

Is there any way to do it with SmartGWT 2.4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the trick. This is not a SmartGWT Label, but something similar. But what's the difference, it's clickable:

```
public YourClass extends VerticalLayout{
  public void YourClass(){
    ...
    initJS(this);
    Label label = new Label("<span onclick=\"setYourFunction(this);\">click here</span>"
            +"<span onclick=\"setYourFunction(this);\">or here</span>");
    // Add label to your grid. This class is just a sample:
    addMember(label);
  }

  private native void initJS (YourClass cs) /*-{
   $wnd.setYourFunction = function (obj) {
       cs.@com.yourpackage.YourClass::onClickFunction(Ljava/lang/String;)('content:'+obj.innerHTML);
   };
  }-*/;

  private void onClickFunction(String s){
    GWT.log(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: How can this label be applied to SmartGWT ListGrid Summary area ? And it should be aligned as per user's will anywhere in summary areal. Explanation with example would do a great help.